# Several Model Estimates Table - Rearranging columns and rows (reprex included)

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, modelsummary

I'm working on creating a table of regression estimates from several models. Here is the data:

```
structure(list(term = c("age_ceo_state__rf", "", "mktrf", "", 
NA, NA), intercept = c("0.390***", "(19.455)", "0.673***", "(23.409)", 
NA, NA), term_2 = c("age_ceo_state__rf", "", "age_firm_state__rf", 
"", "mktrf", ""), intercept_2 = c("0.209***", "(9.449)", "0.405***", 
"(15.511)", "0.417***", "(13.255)"), term_3 = c("age_ceo_state__rf", 
"", "age_firm_state__rf", "", "mktrf", ""), intercept_3 = c("0.209***", 
"(9.449)", "0.405***", "(15.511)", "0.417***", "(13.255)")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here is how it looks right now: [image: original]

And target table:
[image: target]

And yes, the term 2 and term 3 coefficients are the same even if it's a different model. I'm looking for a programmatic way to select the most complete set of terms, move them to term 1 column (notice the order of the terms changed), and set the missing cells to blank. This is a common layout and a lot of regression reporting packages use that layout; I just can't wrap my head around the elegant and flexible way to move the terms around. Apologies for tagging `modelsummary` an amazing package in R for regression tables even though this problem does not directly involve it but the author may have an insight in how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite clumsy. But I think you are looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id =as.integer(gl(n(),2,n()))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("term")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  add_count(value) %>% 
  mutate(x =  value[n=max(n)]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(id1 =as.integer(gl(n(),max(id),n()))) %>% 
  group_by(id, id1) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(name, id, sep="_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(term = ifelse(row_number() == 2, NA_character_, x), .before=1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(id, id1, value, n, name, x))
```

```
  term               intercept intercept_2 intercept_3
  <chr>              <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      
1 age_ceo_state__rf  0.390***  0.209***    0.209***   
2 NA                 (19.455)  (9.449)     (9.449)    
3 age_firm_state__rf 0.673***  0.405***    0.405***   
4 NA                 (23.409)  (15.511)    (15.511)   
5 mktrf              NA        0.417***    0.417***   
6 NA                 NA        (13.255)    (13.255)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is a bit of a problem though. Mkt_rf has a NA in the "intercept" column while the original tables has values for mkt_rf in "intercept". Age_firm_state__rf coefficients and tstats are switched with mktrf for the first column.